# IntelliJ plugin invoke rename refactoring

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for IntelliJ that does a couple of things. One of the things that it performs is a rename of all references if they don't meet a specific style guideline (think of it like a style police officer that checks code styles before saving). What I'd like to do is the following (from within an existing `AnAction`):

1. Find all usages of a given identifier.
2. For each usage, rename the identifier to a different identifier.

Clearly, this is the exact workflow that the rename refactoring uses. So, my question is: How do I invoke the rename refactoring, given a `PsiElement` (or even just a `String` representation of the identifier), from within an existing `AnAction` (i.e. I want to do multiple things in succession, this is just one of them, so I don't want the user to have to go back through the refactoring menu for each thing they want to perform).

Comment: I would just look into IntelliJ source code and used what I need...

Comment: @Meo Yeah, so I'm having difficulty finding what I need... that's the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RefactoringFactory.getInstance(project).createRename()
```